# Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 5, column: 2, Syntax error

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension

Writing my first extention and keep getting this issue

```
{
    "name":  "Hello extentions",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3
    "action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

"browser_action" instead of "action" dont help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma after

```
"manifest_version": 3
```

which makes this JSON file syntactically invalid. Try adding a comma:

```
{
    "name":  "Hello extentions",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```